# Intent filter not working on Galaxy tab (Froyo)

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen

I'm writing an app and code to start the app on the home key press looks like this.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

It's working on the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 (Honeycomb) but not on the Galaxy Tab (Froyo) and I can't figure out why. I've searched the web but couldn't find any solution.

I tried reinstalling the app, restarting the device but still it won't work.

Is there a setting I have to set or something on the Samsung Tab? After the installation of the app, if I press the home screen I have to be prompted with a dialog which should ask me which launcher I want to use, the default homescreen or my app.

The dialog appears on the 10.1 tablet but not on the Galaxy Tab. What is causing this?

Comment: well I need to start the activity from the home button using the android.intent.category.HOME intent. but It won't work on the galaxy tab running froyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the intent works now. I really don't know why it did not work before on Froyo, I didn't make ay changes whatsoever... Thanks anyway! :)